# Java jButton and jTextArea

Tags: java, swing

I am having a problem outputting certain information to my jTextArea. At the moment, When I click a button, the information is being drawn from an arrayString and output using System.out.print. I have another panel that holds the jTextArea and instead of getting the information to print on the System.out.print, I would like to get it to print on the jTextArea instead. I am sure it is simple enough, I am just not sure how to do it.

This is my ActionListener for my button:

```
jbPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jbPlay.addActionListener(this);

            System.out.println(MyFrame.shape1.getArrayList());


        }
    });
```

And here is my class for the panel which contains the jTextArea

```
ublic ActionPanel() {
    initComponents();


    jtaWoof = new JTextArea();
    jtaWoof.setVisible(true);

    jtaWoof.setEditable(true);
    jtaWoof.setSize(900,400);
    jtaWoof.setBackground(Color.white);
    this.add(jtaWoof);}
```

I have also created getters and setters for the jtaWoof; not sure if I needed to or not!

```
public JTextArea getJtaWoof() {
    return jtaWoof;
}

public void setJtaWoof(JTextArea jtaWoof) {
    this.jtaWoof = jtaWoof;
}
```

Thank You in advance for any help, it is very much appreciated!

Comment: Why are you adding the same `ActionListener` multiple times to the `jbPlay` button?

Answer (score 1):

or you can just use append..

public void append(String str)

Appends the given text to the end of the document. Does nothing if the model is null or the string is null or empty.

Parameters:
    str - the text to insert
See Also:
    insert(java.lang.String, int)

Example

```
jtaWoof.append(MyFrame.shape1.getArrayList().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
System.out.println(MyFrame.shape1.getArrayList());
```

with

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        jtaWoof.setText(jtaWoof.getText()+"\n"+MFrame.shape1.getArrayList());
        // or use append()
        //jtaWoof.append(MFrame.shape1.getArrayList()+"\n");
    }
}
```

This will replace the text of the `JTextArea` with the text of the `JTextArea` plus a newline plus the new text.  I would caution you to be careful since if the amount of text isn't limited in some way you could run into performance problems.  Especially since this is run on the EDT (via the `invokeLater(..)` method.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. It is still saying that it can't find the variable jtaWoof?

Comment: You don't show enough of your code to know whether or not `jtaWoof` is in scope of the `ActionListener`.

Comment: The jtfWoof class is private. Is there a way to use this in another class? I am very new to programming so sorry about the lack of information.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that still doesn't tell us whether or not the anonymous inner `ActionListener` has access to it or not.  How are these methods spread across files?  Is there a main `JPanel` or something that contains the references to `jbPlay` and `jtaWoof`?  There's just not enough code here to really provide a solution.

Comment: Sorry. There are three panels. One (bottom) which contains references to jbPlay among other things.(A slider, and other buttons.) A top panel which contains code for letting me draw shapes. And the panel which contains only myjTextArea (jtaWoof)

Comment: You should pass a reference for either `jtaWoof` or the panel containing it (with the `getJtaWoof()` method) to `jbPlay` when it is created.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I have no idea how to pass the reference. I have been looking at code for the past 20 odd hours and nothing is making sense to me lol :(